# Compressing.copying and uncompressing from command line

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to create a batch file hwich will compress a folder, then copy it to some server and then uncompress it.

I am able to compress the local folder, but when I am trying to copy it, the compressed version is nt getting copied, instead it uncompress internally (may be) and then copy it to server. I am  using the followings command from command line...

XCOPY D:\SourceFolder* E:\Dummy /s /i

Any help much appreciated
Thanks in advance

Comment: how did you create the compressed folder?

Answer (score 2):

When you compress a folder in Windows, it does not create a ZIP file that can be directly copied to a new location in compressed format.

The alternative is to use the appropriate tool (I forget which one) to create a ZIP file of the contents. The compressed ZIP file can be copied to the server, and Windows Explorer will treat the ZIP file almost the same as if it was a folder.

Comment: for example 7-zip, it includes a [command line](http://www.dotnetperls.com/7-zip-examples) version